# JQuery adding events to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I am just trying to create some dynamic elements and then attach an event to them using only JQuery.
The buttons should launch an alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/XGb7w/1/

```
$(function(){   

    $('#add').on("click",function(){addItem()});


    function addItem() {
        var listItem = '<li>' +  '<button class="checkBtn"></button>' + '<button class="crossBtn"></button>' + '</li>';
        $('ul').append(listItem);
    }


    $('.crossBtn').on("click", function() {
        alert() // Doesn't alert why not?
    });



    $('.checkBtn').on("click", function() {
        alert();// Doesn't alert why not?
    })

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/XGb7w/2/

Comment: You had 3 `;`s missing in your code.  You should be careful, this will probably cause problems in the future.

Comment: I just was being reckless getting the jsfiddle up. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you set the on handler at the document level.

http://jsfiddle.net/fbNY9/

```
$(function () {

    $('#add').on("click", function () {
        addItem();
    });

    function addItem() {
        var listItem = '<li>' + '<button class="checkBtn" />' + '<button class="crossBtn" />' + '</li>';
        $('ul').append(listItem);
    }

    $(document).on("click",".crossBtn", function () {
        alert(); // Doesn't alert why not?
    });

    $(document).on("click",'.checkBtn', function () {
        alert(); // Doesn't alert why not?
    });

});
```

Comment: This is the proper way of handling the issue, it's called event delegation. You attach the event higher in the DOM and listen for the event on the proper target.